# How can the gridlines in QGIS be set to be curved lines (neat circles) around polar region (azimuthal projection)?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, circle, azimuth

I am trying to present a map of our polar regions using QGIS software.  I am using an azimuthal (polar) projection.  I have added a graticule (gridlines) to the map as a background, which are at 10 degrees lat/long intervals.

However, instead of having neat circles around the pole, the mapping output shows straight lines between the 10 degree longitude intervals.  Is is possible to get a curved line between the longitude intervals?  I realize that a workaround is to create a shapefile with the 10 degree gridlines and upload it to my map, but I would prefer a more elegant solution.

[image: Map in polar azimuthal projection showing lines]

Comment: Maybe this can help? https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/419140/88814

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think there is a way.

The solution is to actually get the grid lines as a layer. These can be download from:
[Natural Earth](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/110m-physical-vectors/)

You will also have to densify them: Vector>Geometry Tools> Densify Geometries...

You can see the results:
https://www.flickr.com/photos/115987875@N04/15852477732/in/pool-qgis/

Comment: This is a useful link to obtain the grid line layer although I was hoping for way to use the graticule function itself.

Answer (score 2):

I found one way to solve this problem, but it seems not make sense.
You can try to change the line style to Arrow. Then change the style of the arrow, like set the 'head length' to 0, so that it will look like a line.
The thing is, arrow feature can be **curved**!!!
[image]

[image]