# Grid of meridians and parallels from South Pole in QGIS print composer

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, print-composer, antimeridian, antarctica

In QGIS 3.16, I'm preparing a map of the emperor penguin colonies in the Antarctica, using the data from the [Quantarctica project](https://www.npolar.no/quantarctica/), but I'm facing a couple of issues with the grid created in the print composer. I set the following variables

[image]

And this is what I've been able to produce

[image]

First, as you can see, the Antimeridian is not represented. Second, any attempt to obtain the Parallels, setting any interval in the Y axis, produces straight lines from Meridian to Meridian, instead of concentric circles from the South Pole. I guess it's a matter of projection and I've tried different EPSGs without success. Any suggestions to overcome these issues?

Comment: What CRS do you use for the project?

Comment: EPSG:3031 Projected coordinate system for Antarctica.

Comment: This is a work around : https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201565/how-can-the-gridlines-in-qgis-be-set-to-be-curved-lines-neat-circles-around-po

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create the grid lines using geometry generator by creating buffers around the south pole. The [distance between Degrees of Latitude is ca. 111 km](https://www.thoughtco.com/degree-of-latitude-and-longitude-distance-4070616). Use this value and mulitply it, using `array_foreach` to create several grid lines at once, here with an interval of 5 degrees (last number in line 3). For adding the antimeridian, see below.

Use this expression: this works if the layer in question is in `EPSG:4326`! If the layer is in `EPSG:3031`, delete the `transform()` function (lines 4 and 9 to 11):

```
collect_geometries (
    array_foreach(
        generate_series (0,30, 5),
        transform (
            buffer (
                make_point (0,0), 
                111000*@element, 
                200
            ),
            'EPSG:3031', 
            'EPSG:4326'
        )
    )
)
```

*Red lines generated with geometry generator and the expression from above; the layer is in `EPSG:4326`:*
[image]

[image]

**Edit: adding antimeridian**

On my first screenshot, the antimeridian seems to appear. This is because I (accidentally) set an offset of 5 degrees for x - so in fact it is not the antimeridian. Maybe that's a bug.

To add the antimeridian, use the same approach: create it with geoemtry generator. For a layer in `EPSG:3031`, use this expression - if the layer is in EPSG:4326, delete lines 1 and 5 to 7:

```
transform (
    make_line (
        make_point (0,-90),
        make_point (180,0))
    ,
    'epsg:4326',
    'epsg:3031'
)
```

You can combine both expressions (for parallels and the antimeridian) in one expression using `collect_geometries (expression_1, expression_2)` (or, similarily, the `union()` function). Be aware to keep or delete the `transform()` function, depending on the layer's CRS. One of the two expressions must have the transform, the other not. As well, the parallels (from the expression above) need to be converted to lines with the function `boundary()`.

So for a layer in `EPSG:4326`, the expression is (for `EPSG:3031` see screenshot):

```
collect_geometries( 
    collect_geometries (
        array_foreach(
            generate_series (0,30, 5),
            transform (
                boundary (
                    buffer (
                        make_point (0,0), 
                        111000*@element, 
                        200
                    )
                ),
                'EPSG:3031', 
                'EPSG:4326'
            )
        )
    ),
    make_line (
        make_point (0,-90),
        make_point (180,0)
    )
)
```

*Screenshots, using a layer in `EPSG:3031`:*
[image]

[image]

Comment: Wonderful @Babel, a nice demonstration of geometry generator power, again

Comment: @Babel, how did you manage to get the Antimeridian (180º) represented? I think I've used the same grid settings and it doesn't show on my map.

Comment: See updated answer with additions: 1) Why in may 1st screenshot there seems to be an antimeridian (there is not, in fact....) and 2) how to add the antimeridian using the same approach.